# What do I have to learn to get done with a 3D racing game for the iPhone? What Tools do I need?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, 3d

I know Java pretty well. I know now most of the Basics in Objective-C.
I know nothing about Photoshop. I know how to use TurboCAD 10 Professional, so I do have some experience in 3D object modelling. Although not much.

What do I have to learn step-by-step, to come to 3D game Development for iPhone? What Tools do I need? Which Books help out? How long did you learn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Learning the basic ins-and-outs of OpenGL ES on the iPhone took me about 3 weeks.  I post some of my observations on the subject [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/08/05/lessons-molecules-opengl-es).  The source code to my Molecules iPhone application, which uses OpenGL ES, is available [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/02/molecules-source-code-now-available).  Maybe you'll be able to find something useful in that example.  However, there's nothing in there that deals with textures, which you'll probably need for your game.  Bill Dudney has [posted source code](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wave_front_obj_textures_working) for a Wavefront OBJ modeler on the iPhone that may help in that regard.  For a good text on OpenGL ES, I'd recommend ["Mobile 3D Graphics: with OpenGL ES and M3G"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123737273).

When it comes to Cocoa development in general, it will take you a little while to get up to speed.  For me, it was about 6 months before I felt comfortable with it, although that was in the more complex Mac desktop environment.  I post some resources for learning Cocoa [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2009/02/13/resources-getting-started-cocoa), although that's by no means an exhaustive list.

I agree with diciu, this is a bit much for someone just starting out on the platform.  I'd find a simpler application or series of targeted applications (that you may never even release) to help you learn the core concepts before you leap into 3-D game design.

Answer (score 3):

Your goal is very ambitious - I think it's a very hard project to tackle as the first project on the iPhone and you'd be better off starting out with a couple of simple Cocoa touch applications to get a feel for the platform.

For a simulation game I would start with experimenting with some physics engine such as [bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(software)). Bullet is C++ and you can use it from Objective-C++.

For rendering 3D you probably want to use [OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that [OpenGL](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide) is worth a look.