# Which books and resources are good to learn OpenGL ES for iPhone OS quickly?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Maybe someone can recommend a book, great website or video training series for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a commonly asked question here:

- [Books on OpenGL ES targeted towards the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081293/books-on-opengl-es-targeted-towards-the-iphone)
- [Learning OpenGL ES 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72288/learning-opengl-es-1-x)
- [What do I have to learn to get done with a 3D racing game for the iPhone? What Tools do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581784/what-do-i-have-to-learn-to-get-done-with-a-3d-racing-game-for-the-iphone-what-to)
- [Want to display a 3D model on the iPhone: how to get started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413919/want-to-display-a-3d-model-on-the-iphone-how-to-get-started)

Answer (score 0):

Jeff LaMarche has also written a pretty good series of articles on his blog about getting started with OpenGL ES. They've definitely helped me out.

Link: [OpenGL From the Ground Up](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html)

Answer (score 0):

search for iPhone 3D Programming, its a nice book and covers both OpenGL ES 1.X and 2.X, it even available [online](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/), (personally I prefer reading from the paper, rather than screen)