# Documentation Regarding iOS Game Development

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos3d

Please provide me some iOS game development documentation for beginners. I do already have knowledge about iOS native application development.

I found some APIs like COCOS2d,COCOS3d, OPEN-GL, OPEN-GL ES, etc. But I am not able to find any specific documentation to learn that easily.

Comment: Amazon lists quite a number of books on writing games for iOS, some of which specifically cover the libraries you're asking about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What resources do you recommend for game programming on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493324/what-resources-do-you-recommend-for-game-programming-on-the-iphone)

Comment: See also [What do I have to learn to get done with a 3D racing game for the iPhone? What Tools do I need?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581784/what-do-i-have-to-learn-to-get-done-with-a-3d-racing-game-for-the-iphone-what-t), [learning iphone game development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720901/learning-iphone-game-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COCOS 2d is powerful library to make iPhone games.
You will find few tutorials on following site- 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials
Learn.cocos2d.Game.Development.with.iOS.5 book written by Steffen Itterheim is also good stuff to start.
Also search on google you will find lots of stuff.

Comment: If you liked the link you can upvote my answer! :)